# Licenses of internal packages?

Tags: oracle, licensing

I heard rumors that some of database packages provided in Oracle database are not necessarily free to use. I thought that all packages like DBMS_UTILITY and DBMS_PROFILER are free to use and doesn't cost any extra.
And I also heard that there might be some kind of log if you have used some of those packages so that Oracle licensing guys could see afterwards how systems are used.

Do you know how it goes? Is there different licenses concerning about usage of internal packages?

Thanks,
Jokke

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I got my answer almost 5 years ago so closing this one does not hurt but maybe would be helpful information for someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBMS_UTILITY and DBMS_PROFILER are both free to use.

The packages (and views) that require additional licensing will generally be part of one of the various [management packs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e10594/options.htm#CIHGFIAF) and are documented in the Licensing Guide.  For example, the DBMS_SQLTUNE package and the V$SQL_MONITOR view are part of the separately licensed Oracle Tuning Pack.  If you use one of these packages or views, the associated entry in DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS should be updated so that the DBA can ensure that the organization is correctly licensed.

Comment: When you say the DBA_F_U_S should be updated, is this something you allow developers to update? Or do you really mean to tell your dba that you're using it and whether he tracks it there or somewhere else is his/her call?

Comment: I meant that Oracle should automatically update that view.  I haven't personally done any testing to verify that, so I don't know if there are caveats where Oracle doesn't update the view automatically.